# Help with PHP and COM

Tags: php, com

What is the best way to communicate with another process in PHP?

Update: Using Windows, PHP 5, calling COM assemblies, COM may or may not be needed, I don't really care.

Update: I am trying to send a command from PHP to Ascom (a control program). I mainly need to execute methods and pass small parameters. I also need to be able to get information from it.

Comment: do you really need to use COM and/or have something that works on Windows ? Or would some Linux-oriented mecanism be OK ? Also, can you modify the code of the other processes ?

Comment: What platform? What kind of process? What do you want to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you want to do? There`s COM but it's badly documented and can't be used in every situation, maybe an alternative approach is more suitable.

Comment: Read the question, I am wondering how to call external processes on Windows. You guys act like all that makes sense on here is the technical questions. This is the third time I had to specify that I want exactly what the question says.

Comment: Protip: when something keeps happening and the one unchanging variable is you, guess what the problem generally is?

Comment: Alright, you win. Though it appears like no one knows

Comment: @Arlen There is no standard for intra-process communication in PHP. If you clarify a bit about what you want to do, what amounts of data you need to transmit for example, and in what intervals, you will probably get some workable ideas and approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use COM quite extensively with PHP, using COM objects built in C++ from our library, with Apache as the web server, on Windows 2003. It has worked pretty well for about five years.

You can instantiate and use a COM object directly in PHP. Looking at the Ascom camera interface given here http://ascom-standards.org/Standards/Index.htm, I would expect it to work fine; something like this:

```
      $camera = new COM('ManufacturerName.Camera'); // COM class name made up
      $camera.NumX = 200;
      $camera.NumY = 200;
      $camera.BinX = 1;
      // Set more properties... then, having set $duration and $light:
      $camera.StartExposure( $duration, $light );
      // etc
```

ie you can use properties and methods just how you would expect. The actual COM class name will be in the docs of your instrument. You may find it in any example code the manufacturer has given you.

If you are using it in a web process, be aware that you will have to re-instantiate the COM objects each time you service an HTTP request, and reconnect to the instrument.

Have a go - you will probably be pleasantly surprised by how straightforward it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet will probably be to write a wrapper that wraps the com assembly using C# or C++. The simplest way to use it would be command line based.

`ASCOM.exe focuser position` would yeild the position of the focuser.

`ASCOM.exe focuser move 25` would move the focuser but wouldn't return until it has been moved.

Make sure that you are taking care of multi-user issues with this! If you have 10 people trying to move the instrument around you will have problems.

**Edit**

In php you make calls to external commands with the `system()` or `exec()` command. You should use `system()` because it blocks until the command completes.

`$pos = system("ASCOM.exe focuser position")`; Would put the position in the `$pos`variable. Remember ASCOM.exe is a program you have created to take these command line args and convert them into the appropriate COM calls.

Read this MS article on making a [COM wrapper in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx#vcwlkcominteroptutorialcreatinganunmanagedcomclasswrapper). If you prefer to use C++, try [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8989aw26(VS.80).aspx) Finally, if you are uncomfortable in either of those languages, you can [access COM objects in powershell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/08/chapter-6-using-objects.aspx#using-com-objects) easily.

Comment: How do I get it to return the position?

Comment: In fact, how do I call it from PHP?

Comment: How do I make a program return something?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of interfaces does ASCOM come with? Did a google search but did find several programs.

Comment: ASCOM is a device independent COM driver for astronomical equipement.